# Rails TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer) on a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After setup a simple token check on the session rails spits out this

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
>
> app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `verify_token'

on this method

so, as i checked seems right.

someone has any idea why this is happening on this method?

```
def verify_token
    @current_user = User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['token'] [:auth_token])    
    if @current_user    
      render json: {message:"verified",  status: 200}    
    else    
      render_unauthorized("Token failed verification")
    end
end
```

Comment: Most probably `request.headers['token']` returns an array, and you're trying to access an `auth_token` key, hence Ruby tries a conversion from the symbol to the array index.

Comment: ahh ok, thank you Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `request.headers['token'] likely contains a string.

When you do

```
request.headers['token'] [:auth_token]
```

You are running the `[]` method on the string, which method is allowed if it contains an integer.

```
'carrot'[2]
=> 'r'
```

But it's not allowed if you use a symbol instead, as it can't automatically convert a symbol into an integer (no implicit conversion)

Probably would be sufficient to do...

```
@current_user = User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['token'])
```